# Determine that an ideal is not a principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and the function $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] \to \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. I found the kernel of the function, namely $(3, 1-\sqrt{-5})$. Now I am trying to prove that the kernel is not a principal ideal. How can I do this?

I know I could use norms to do it. But what do I need to compute to conclude that this ideal is not a principal ideal?

Answer (score 2):

The norm of a putative generator $\alpha$ must divide that of $3$, which is $9$
and that of $1-\sqrt{-5}$, namely $6$. Therefore $N\alpha=1$ or $3$.

If $N\alpha=1$ then $\alpha=\pm1$. That's impossible as $\phi(\pm1)\ne0$.

But $N\alpha=3$ is impossible: there are no integers with $a^2+5b^2=3$.

Comment: And if there exists two integers $a, b$ such that $a^2 + 5b^2 = x$, then it is a principal ideal?

Comment: If there are two integers with $a^2+5b^2=x$ then there is a principal ideal of norm $x$ (but there might also be a non-principal ideal of norm $x$).

Comment: And why is it needed that $\phi(±1) \neq 0$? Can't you say that there aren't two integers such that $a^2+5b^2=0$? (Which is true of course)